# Regex only replace within Group

Tags: regex

Using regex i want to remove all < b > and < /b > tags within < head > but NOT within < section >

Input:

```
<head>
    <b>some text</b>
    <b>some more text</b>
</head>
<section>
    <b>some text</b>
    <b>some more text</b>
</section>
```

Desired Output:

```
<head>
    some text
    some more text
</head>
<section>
    <b>some text</b>
    <b>some more text</b>
</section>
```

Comment: Use the queryselector of Javascript for this result you wish for, Regex isn’t the solution here.

Comment: what's your OS?

Answer (score -1):

</?b>(?=([\w\n\r\t\s<>/]*</head>))

Js solution

Comment: please add explanation

Comment: Searching for all <b> and </b> tags that are followed by any symbol and "</head>" string (positive lookahead). [\w\n\r\t\s<>/] can be modified to include dots, comas etc.